# find control in masterpage

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I am trying to set a label in master page from content page, not using FindControl. So, in master page I declared:

```
public partial class MainMasterPage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{

    public string UserOfficeLabel 
    {
        get { return lblUserOffice.Text; }
        set { lblUserOffice.Text = value; } 
    }
    public string OfficeLocationLabel
    {
        get { return lblOfficeLocation.Text; }
        set { lblOfficeLocation.Text = value; } 
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    ....
    }
}
```

"UserOfficeLabel" and "OfficeLocationLabel" are labels on master page. Then in content page (.aspx) I added the following directive under "Page" directive:

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Main/MainMasterPage.master" %>
```

In conent page's code behind (.cs file) I try to access/set the label:

```
Master.UserOfficeLabel = ...
```

but UserOfficeLabel is not an option for Master (VS Intellisense does not list it as an option). When I add it anyway, it says "MainMasterPage.UserOfficeLabel is inaccessible to its protection level"

Comment: why you don't want to use FindControl?

Comment: "I have a screw, and I want to screw it into something, but I don't want to use a screwdriver. Please help. No, I will not tell you why."

Comment: Using FindControl is bad from an OO/Encapsulation standpoint, and should be avoided where possible. This is similar to exposing the private variables by pointers in C++. I hope this answers your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find what you are looking for here:
http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2005/07/16/mastertype-in-asp-net-2-0.aspx. 
In theory when you compile you should see the code below inside a partial class

```
    Public Shadows ReadOnly Property Master() As otc
    Get
        Return CType(MyBase.Master,otcMaster)
    End Get
End Property
```

I've done something like what you are trying by declaring a variable

```
Dim LocalMasterPageRef As MyMasterPageName
LocalMasterPageRef = CType(Me.Master, MyMasterPageName)
...
LocalMasterPageRef.xxxx
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Juan. When I trace the code it seems it gets the correct label on the master page and sets its text correctly but the label on the page does not change unless I refresh the page.

Comment: The changing of master page labels occur in the content page's dropdown lists' SelectedIndexChanged event hanlder and this dropdown list (along with a bunch of other controls) are inside an Ajax update panel. Not sure if this makes a difference.

Comment: Not sure was going on...1) I don't understand what is the connection between the handler event on the master page and the need to change the label from the child window 2) I would look the Ajax update panel, I think I have read a couple of times problems related to that component. Good luck

Comment: About the first point maybe this has something to do about it http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dct97kc3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: The dropdownlist is not in master page, it is in content page. When selection changes I need to update the labels on the master page accordingly. The event hanlder is in content page's .cs file.

Comment: For anyone who might have the same problem, here is the answer: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889081/update-label-on-masterpage-from-content-page-with-updatepanel-without-full-postb http://forums.asp.net/p/1802476/4975264.aspx/1?[link]+does+not+contain+a+definition+and+no+extension+of+error

Comment: I'm glad you found the answer